# mysql join same table with another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name `tbl_user`
[image]

This table contain a column name `db_responsibleid` contain the id of the responsible of this person and this person is in this table also
example mohammad have `db_uid=1` and samir have `db_responsibleid=1` this mean that mohammad is responsible for samir

also i have another table name `tbl_department` the table user contain the id of the department on the column name `db_udepartment`

I try to have the name of the department and the name and the last name of the responsible where `db_uid='$id'`

$id will be getting from url

this is the query that i use

```
     SELECT 
     user.db_uid,
     user.db_fname,
     user.db_lname,
     user.db_username,
     user.db_pass,
     user.db_email,
     user.db_phone,
     user.db_jobtitle,
     user.db_level,
     user.db_isemployee,
     user.db_responsibleid,
     user.db_companyname,
     user.db_udepartment,
     tbl_department.db_department,
     tbl_department.db_did,
     parent.db_responsibleid,
     parent.db_fname as pfname,
     parent.db_lname as plname,
     parent.db_uid
     from tbl_user as user,tbl_department 
     join tbl_user as parent 
     on 
     user.db_responsibleid=parent.db_uid 
     where 
     user.db_udepartment=tbl_department.db_did 
     and 
     user.db_uid='$id'
```

But this query give me this error **Unknown column 'user.db_responsibleid' in 'on clause'**

**How can i solve this problem and get all information with the name of the responsible and the name of the department ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix implizit and explizit join.
If you decided to use join you have to do it everywhere:

```
from tbl_user as user
 join tbl_department on user.db_udepartment=tbl_department.db_did 
 join tbl_user as parent 
 on 
 user.db_responsibleid=parent.db_uid 
 where 
 user.db_uid='$id'
```

Hint: use prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection